# Starting QGIS with virtualenv Python?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2

is there any means of telling QGIS to use a different Python installation than the default, system-wide one?
E.g. use some virtualenv Python `/myvirtualenv/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin/python`?

Background: I'm developing a custom plugin that uses some modules which are only installed in a certain virtualenv, but not system-wide.

The virtualenv is allowed to access system-wide packages, so the qgis core libs should still be accessible when using that virtualenv.

The only solution that I see right now is to install the required modules in the system-wide Python. However, I'd like to keep them in the virtualenv only, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first load your virtual environment and then start QGIS **in the same terminal** where you loaded the virtual environment.

for example in linux:

```
source /myvirtualenv/bin/activate
qgis
```

Comment: this didn't work for me (QGIS 3.4.4, linux mint 18)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot guarantee this will work but perhaps you could try setting a custom variable to load your python version:

[image: System Environment]