# Make QGIS use a conda virtual environment for python libraries

Tags: qgis, python, anaconda

I wanted to install a plugin, but it requires scipy. Thus I realized that QGIS use the default python3 installation. I tried to launch it from a conda virtual environment, as advised in [this related stackexchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131932/starting-qgis-with-virtualenv-python), but I end up with the ["Couldn't load SIP module." Issue#37783](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37783) (which isn't resolved imho).

My QGIS installation is system-wide (`/usr/bin/qgis`).

How can I make QGIS use a conda virtual environment for python libraries?

**QGIS and OS versions**

| QGIS version | 3.16.1-Hannover | QGIS code revision | b381a90dca |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Compiled against Qt | 5.12.8 | Running against Qt | 5.12.8 |
| Compiled against GDAL/OGR | 3.0.4 | Running against GDAL/OGR | 3.0.4 |
| Compiled against GEOS | 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 | Running against GEOS | 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 |
| Compiled against SQLite | 3.31.1 | Running against SQLite | 3.31.1 |
| PostgreSQL Client Version | 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) | SpatiaLite Version | 4.3.0a |
| QWT Version | 6.1.4 | QScintilla2 Version | 2.11.2 |
| Compiled against PROJ | 6.3.1 | Running against PROJ | Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020 |
| OS Version | Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS |  |  |
| Active python plugins | openlayers_plugin; MetaSearch; processing |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

Installing QGIS with conda should do the trick https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qgis

Comment: Currently, this version conflicts with local Qt installation on Ubuntu. So you either need to change your library path, or install on its own environment.